# What are memory mapped page and anonymous page?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, memory-mapped-files, memory-mapping

I am not able to understand memory mapped page and anonymous page in linux. Can someone please explain it with an example? What are the kernel data structures related to them?

Comment: mmaped file is the virtual memory page backed by page cache; and anonymous page (mmap with flag MAP_ANONYMOUS) is virtual memory page, backed by zero page (will return only zeroes on read; write prohibited by flag). When you does first write into anonymous page, new physical page will be allocated and filled with zeroes. This page will be mapped for your anon. page and write will be restarted.

Comment: Try this: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/mm/memory.html (full book is here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/tlk.html) as online book; or Understanding the Linux Kernel by Daniel P. Bovet as offline book (I think about it as commented kernel sources listing).

Comment: Where did you hear the term memory mapped page? Any instance or any reference?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The correct terms are memory mapped *files* and anonymous mappings. When referring to memory mapping, one is usually referring to mmap(2). There are 2 categories for using mmap. One category is SHARED vs PRIVATE mappings. The other category is FILE vs ANONYMOUS mappings. Mixed together you get the 4 following combinations:

1. PRIVATE FILE MAPPING
2. SHARED FILE MAPPING
3. PRIVATE ANONYMOUS MAPPING
4. SHARED ANONYMOUS MAPPING

A File Mapping specifies a file, on disk, that will have N many bytes mapped into memory. The function mmap(2) takes, as its 4th argument a file descriptor to the file to be mapped into memory. The 5th argument is the number of bytes to be read in, as an offset. The typical process of using mmap to create a memory mapped file goes

1. open(2) file to get a file descriptor.
2. fstat(2) the file to get the size from the file descriptor data structure.
3. mmap(2) the file using the file descriptor returned from open(2).
4. close(2) the file descriptor.
5. do whatever to the memory mapped file.

When a file is mapped in as PRIVATE, changes made are not committed to the underlying file. It is a PRIVATE, in-memory copy of the file. When a file is mapped SHARED, changes made are committed to the underlying file by the kernel automatically. Files mapped in as shared can be used for what is called Memory Mapped I/O, and IPC. You would use a memory mapped file for IPC instead of a shared memory segment if you need the persistence of the file

If you use strace(1) to watch a process initialize, you will notice that the different sections of the file are mapped in using mmap(2) as private file mappings. The same is true for system libs.

Examples of output from strace(1) where mmap(2) is being used to map in libraries to the process.

```
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=42238, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 42238, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ff7ca71e000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\356\341n8\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1926760, ...}) = 0
mmap(0x386ee00000, 3750152, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x386ee00000
```

Anonymous mappings are not backed by a file. To be specific, the 4th (file descriptor) and 5th (offset) argument of mmap(2) are not even used when the MAP_ANONYMOUS flag is used as the 3rd argument to mmap(2). An alternative to using the MAP_ANONYMOUS flag is to use /dev/zero as the file.

The word 'Anonymous' is, to me, a poor choice in that it sounds as if the file is mapped anonymously. Instead, it is the file that is anonymous, ie. there isn't a file specified.

The most common use of anonymous private mappings is the heap and stack segments of a process. You could use a shared anonymous mapping so that applications could share a region of memory, but I do not know the reason why you wouldn't use SYSV or POSIX shared memory instead.

Since memory mapped in using Anonymous mappings is guaranteed to be zero filled, it could be useful for some applications that expect/require zero filled regions of memory to use mmap(2) in this way instead of the malloc(2) + memset(2) combo.

Comment: Good reply, but I think the question was supposed to refer the anonymous pages and pages in page cache. They are not user space things.

Comment: *it could be useful for some applications that expect/require zero filled regions* - Indeed, glibc `calloc` will skip zeroing for pages it knows came fresh from the kernel, so they're still "clean", so e.g. reading it can still get multiple virtual pages backed by the same shared page of zeros.  (Except for the first page of a large mapping, where glibc malloc puts its metadata in the 16 bytes before the pointer it actually returns.)

Answer (score 11):

As i understand anonymous pages is so named, because they have no named filesystem source, while mapped pages is a mapping of concrete file. For example you can get anonymos pages using a simple malloc operation in any userspace process...

About kernel structures:
Obviously it is **struct page**, but in case of the anonymos pages you will have **struct anon_vma** sitting in page->mapping, and in case of mapped pages - **struct address_space**, which is connected with concrete inode.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what memory mapped page means? So I am not going to talk about it.

Regarding anonymous pages, it's usually referred when kernel does page frame reclamation. Instances of anonymous pages include process's stack, heap, shared memory, and any modified shared libraries. In Linux, all dynamic shared libraries are mapped to a process's virtual memory address space through a system call like the following:

```
firo@linux-6qg8:~> strace -e mmap,openat ls 2>&1 |grep -A1 libc.so
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
mmap(NULL, 3906144, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0)
```

Any write on the page which belongs to MAP_PRIVATEed files/libraries will trigger a changing from file-backend page to anonymous page.

By definition, the anonymous page, also called anonymous memory, is just a kind of page which doesn't have backend device to be swapped to when kernel does page frame reclamation. That is the reason why Linux supports swap area.

There are two kinds of kernel data structures relating to anonymous pages.

1. In order to reclaim an anonymous page, kernel have to know all the processes which are using the anonymous page for changing their PTEs(Page table entry). We call this as reverse mapping or rmap.

   struct address_space is used by shared memory to maintain the reverse mapping.

   struct anon_vma is used by rest of anonymous pages to maintain the reverse mapping.
2. Kernel uses LRU algorithm to reclaim page frame. 
   For kernel 5.0+, check struct lruvec in struct pglist_data